# How to open custom album on Windows Phone Mango

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I'm using this code to open Pictures Library:

```
PhotoChooserTask imageChooser = new PhotoChooserTask();
imageChooser.Show();
```

So is there any way to open desired album, for example "Saved Pictures" or some user created album?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no **constructor** for **PictureAlbum**, **Picture.Album** is read only preventing reassignment of pictures between already existing albums and there is not method to submit a picture album.

You can place images in the media library using [MediaLibrary.SavePicture Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.savepicture.aspx) and you can access them.

If you want to access the from Media Library in Windows Phone you can do this way:

```
 MediaLibrary m = new MediaLibrary();

foreach (var r in m.Pictures)
{
Stream imageStream = r.GetImage();

var imageToShow = new Image()
{
Source = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(r.GetImage())
};

lstImageFromMediaLibrary.Items.Add(imageToShow);
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I dont want open images. I just need open the album.

Comment: In the current SDK, you can only save to the Saved Pictures album or the Camera Roll album. There's no way to create your an app-specific album at the moment.

Comment: I think this is what you need http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/encode-and-decode-images-in-wp7